# Url in a text column multiline

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, content-type, column

I've an issue in Sharepoint 2010 with a column text multi line and enhanced rich text is selected, I've to put an url inside.

My column is defined inside a content type and this one is on different document library.

In my script when I add a document with an url in my field sometimes it works sometimes it's disabled.

To enable it, I've to put this and some other times, nothing works and the url is grey without link

```
item["myCol"] = "<a href='"www.google.be"'>www.google.be</a>";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't it be like this? Removed the extra quotation marks around URL, and added http:// (just a best practice, may not be related to the issue).

```
item["myCol"] = "<a href='http://www.google.be'>www.google.be</a>";
```